# HTTP error 404 from a RESTful web service deployed in Jboss 7.1.1

Tags: java, rest, jboss7.x

I have successfully deployed a small RESTful web service in Jboss 7.1.1, but when I tried testing it using this url: http://localhost:8080/auth/webresources/test/hello/Jumbu it returns HTTP error 404. the code for the service is below:

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestService {
@GET
@Path("hello/{name}")
public String sayHello(@PathParam("name") String name) {
    return "Welcome " + name;
} 
}
```

my ApplicationConfig class is given below:

```
@ApplicationPath("/webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>>();
    addRestResourceClasses(resources);
    return resources;
}
private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
    resources.add(com.jcjoof.jcjoofaws.TestService.class);
}
}
```

I can't really figure out what is wrong, Kindly help..

Comment: Is `auth` set as your web root somewhere?
From the config you show, it looks like your url should be:
`http://localhost:8080/webresources/test/hello/Jumbu`

Comment: This is really strange to me because auth is my context root, that is the reason why I am using http://localhost:8080/auth/webresources/test/hello/Jumbu. I need help please..

Comment: The log file of your service should contain a line like `JBAS018210: Register web context: /auth`. Can you see that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your sayHello method is missing a slash.. Try using `@Path("/hello/{name}")`

Also, try adding an empty web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
</web-app>
```

Comment: can you share your web.xml? Maybe you are using resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix context-param, which contradicts @ApplicationPath("/webresources")

Comment: Is it a must for me to use web.xml? because I am not using web.xml

Comment: According to http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.3.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#Installation_Configuration you need an empty web.xml.. (I thought It wasn't necessary.. but I guess I was wrong)